# Why would old "chime" generators go out of tune?

Tags: tone-control

I've been in many situations where multiple independent electronic "chime" generators are playing at the same time [1], but on rare occasions they are several semitones out of tune with one another (don't have a recording right now). Presumably they were in tune when shipped from the factory, and saw the same ambient conditions over time (likely decades). How is this possible?

My best guess is that are using an external RC oscillator for tone generation and the capacitor's dielectric is giving out. However, I don't understand why the designer would use that solution decades ago when:

- They could have used a 60hz AC signal as a common reference
- Crystals existed and were likely < $1 in quantity
- Do ceramic or on-chip (silicon) oscillators suffer from the same problems?

[1] Here is one example from the Kyoto train station, where two chimers are heard: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWJeWWrqbCg&t=3510s

Comment: Because cost is more important than satisfying the small percentage of people who will notice if it isn't exactly in tune.

Comment: A:  To produce a 200 Hz to 2 kHz tone based on a 60 Hz reference requires a frequency-locked loop.  Expensive.  B:  A crystal might be $1, but one R-C is $0.05.  Also, the tones in the audio clip are computer-generated.  C:  And it they were not, why do you ***assume*** that they ever were "in tune"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they did use crystals they would not likely change sound perceptively over their life.

Purpose-built chime generator chips such as the iconic bipolar Siemens [SAB060x](http://doc.chipfind.ru/pdf/siemens/sab0600.pdf) series and later CMOS parts from other makers did not use crystals.

[image]

Some parts designed for video game use included at least the option to use crystals (sometimes NTSC color burst crystals which were relatively inexpensive), but they were not as easy to use, simple, reliable and inexpensive. It would not be easy to use mains frequency as a reference, and places like Japan have some areas which are 50Hz and some that are 60Hz.

The chime tones produced by such an untrimmed RC oscillator circuit would generally have an accurate relationship to each other, but not so great absolute frequency accuracy, **even out of the factory**. Maybe a couple semitones (10%-ish) depending on the tolerances of the components and the chip-to-chip variations. If they added a trimpot to eliminate that initial error, that could well be a source of change in the frequency as time and air pollution takes their toll.

In the case of the Siemens triple-tone part, the three frequencies (660Hz, 550Hz, 440Hz) are digitally generated by dividing down a master 13.2kHz RC oscillator by 20, 24 and 30 respectively, and the tone decay also is derived from the same oscillator.

[Here](https://youtu.be/pX4ZyhJTbhY?si=_0L-ZQaWOB411STS) is the (possibly painful to you) range of sounds produced by the SAB0600 as an adjustment pot is changed.

Answer (score 2):

> Presumably they were in tune when shipped from the factory, and saw the same ambient conditions over time (likely decades). How is this possible?

No two oscillators in this universe¹ are identical. In lower-cost electronics, that's doubly true: simple RC oscillators probably suffice to play a "bell" sound / "chime". These can easily be off +- 5% even under normal conditions.

Train installations typically are long-lived. So, even if you had a 20 ppm (that's 0.002 %) accurate quartz in 1987 when you hung the chime, +- 5ppm per year in aging is quite a normal spec, and while it's not likely that it ages for 36 years at the same speed in the same direction, a plausible accuracy range now becomes 20 ppm + 36 a · 5 ppm/a = 200 ppm = 0.02%, and for a tone of 5 kHz, that starts to become noticable if overlayed with another tone that doesn't have that error.

> They could have used a 60hz AC signal as a common reference

Hardship in Japan would be that Western Japan is at 60 Hz and Eastern is at 50 Hz. Generally, often not desirable: You want your chimes to sound deeper in the evening when everyone's running their electric heaters? Primary grid regulation happens through frequency. Also note that distributed speaker systems could do clever things like a high DC supply with trigger signals superimposed. I don't know how JR implements that, though.

> Crystals existed and were likely < $1 in quantity

Sure, but they do still age, and so do the load capacitors, voltage supplies…

> Do ceramic or on-chip (silicon) oscillators suffer from the same problems?

On-chip oscillators are usually just RC oscillators. Ceramic/SAW are rarely better than Quartzes, and MEMS oscillators are a relatively new, relatively expensive technology.

Also not that you *might not be hearing what was played*; even at walking speeds (1.5 m/s), speed of sound in air isn't that high (300 m/s), so that the Doppler shift of you walking away from a speaker is audible (\$\Delta f = f_0 \cdot - \frac{1.5\text{ m/s}}{300\text{ m/s}} = f_0\cdot -5·10⁻³\$; say \$f_0= 2\text{ kHz}\$, you get a doppler shift of 10 Hz.) Trombone effects of a subway pressing the air out of a tube across a speaker can probably be larger.

¹ as long as you can observe both, quantum entanglement is a thing…